# Why does my Properties panel cover my whole active 3D Viewport when I press P?

Tags: interface

Why does my Properties panel cover my whole active 3D Viewport when I press P? It never used to do this, it always toggled my Properties panel open and closed, as it should. But just starting today, when I press P, it covers my whole active viewport, but it doesn't even show any of the properties on the panel. Also interesting is that once the panel has covered the viewport, pressing P again will not close it again -- the only way to get it to close is press ESC, and then the panel just goes back to being open normally, not fully closed:

By the way, I'm using 2.70, and this problem continues even if I quit & restart Blender, and also if I reboot my computer.

[image]

Also interesting is the fact that if the Tools panel is open when I press P, the Properties panel will cover even it:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>P</kbd> you are starting the game engine.

<kbd>N</kbd> opens and closes the Properties panel.

Comment: Ugg...that's an easy way to imbibe humility...thanks.
XP

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is not the properties panel. The keyboard shortcut <kbd>P</kbd> start the blender game engine, "P" for play. If you were to add in some object and hit P this would be very apparent that it is not the properties panel.

Pressing <kbd>P</kbd> at the default scene.

[image]